# String initializer for optional primitive types: Int? Double? Float? etc

Tags: ios, swift, string, initialization, type-systems

Is it possible to have an extension for all of the above types without specifying each type individually?

For example, here is such extension for `Double`:

```
extension String {
  init?(_ value: Double?) {
    if let nonOpt = value {
      self.init(nonOpt)
    } else {
      return nil
    }
  }
}


let nonOpt: Double = 1

let opt: Double? = 1

let string = String(opt)

print(string)
```

I'd like to allow string initialization with optional type if it is possible to initialize string with the original type.

Comment: opt.map { String($0) }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean something like this

```
extension String {
    init?<T : CustomStringConvertible>(_ value : T?) {
        guard let value = value else { return nil }
        self.init(describing: value)
    }
}
```

or

```
extension String {
    init?<T : LosslessStringConvertible>(_ value : T?) {
        guard let value = value else { return nil }
        self.init(value)
    }
}
```

Comment: Good Answer, can i ask you question, how you know this `protocols` specially second one  are you mastering `Swift Standard Library`

Comment: I would advise against this. This is what `map` is for. The same way we don't have to redefine every API that takes a `T` to have a version that takes a `[T]` (because we can just use `array.map(f)`), we shouldn't define every API that takes a `T` to have a version that takes a `T?`. That's what `Optional.map` is for.

Comment: Thank you. Accepting your answer since it answers question. However, in this case I'm going with `map(String.init)`

Answer (score 3):

Rather than declaring an custom initializer, just use `map` to map the value to a `String` as such:

```
let optDouble: Double? = nil
let optionalDoubleString = opt.map { String($0) }
let optInt: Int? = nil
let optionalIntString = opt.map { String($0) }
```

Comment: No need to use a closure. You can pass the string initializer to the map method 
`opt.map(String.init)`. Note that you are mapping `opt` instead of `optInt` and `optDouble`